# Let $(G, *)$ be a group and let $g\in G$, if the inverse of $g$ is written as $-g$, show that $-(-g) = g$

Tags: group-theory

My approach so far was:
Let $G$ be a group, and let $g \in G$. By definition of groups, we have that every element in $G$ has a unique inverse which is denoted as $-g$. So we have that $g*-g = e$. I wanted to say from this $g = e*-(-g) = -(-g)$ but this seems like a really big stretch.

Is there anyway to approach this using just group theory?

Comment: By uniqueness of inverse elements in groups, as $g*-g=e$, $g$ must be the inverse of $-g$, i.e., $g=-(-g)$.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of $g$, written $-g$, is the element of $G$ such that $g*(-g)=e$ and $-g*g=e$.

Reverse the order of those two equalities and we get $-g*g=e$ and $g*(-g)=e$.

This shows that $g$ is the inverse of $-g$. In other words, $-(-g)=g$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition $g \ast -g = e$, so the inverse of $-g$ (which by the convention we write as $-(-g)$) is $g$.

(NB this uses the fact that in a group the right inverse of an element coincides with its left inverse, which, since you're asking this question, you may or may not have at your disposal.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is easiest to solve this by stating "prove $-(-g) = g$" as "prove that $g$ is the inverse of the element $-g$."

Given $g \in G$, we know that $g$ must have a unique inverse $-g$ such that $(g) \ast (-g) = e$. But we want to find the inverse of the element $-g$, namely $-(-g)$ by our introduced notation, which from this previous equation must be $g$.